# dht11 sensor only retuning unexpected number of pulse often

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to make a simple  water pump controller using a dth11 to make the pump turn on more frequently when the temperature is higher. i have it working but every 4th or 5th time i call measure on the dht11 sensor i get an error saying "InvalidPulseCount: Expected 82 but got 0 pulses" or "InvalidPulseCount: Got more than 82 pulses".  I have added  try  block that is stopping the program from crashing  but would really like to figure out why it is happening. I also had to edit the [dht.py lib](https://github.com/ikornaselur/pico-libs/blob/master/src/dht11/dht.py) to have 82 instead of 84 as the default expected pulses because that was what was commonly returned.

here is my main.py file

```
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep_ms
import dht
import I2C_LCD_driver

sensor = dht.DHT11(Pin(28))
lcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
pump = Pin(7, machine.Pin.OUT)
counter = 0
pumpTime = 30
normalTime = 60
hotTime = 30

lowTemp = 19

# sensor variables only updated every 3 loops
lastMesure = 1
temp = 0
humid = 0
first = True
                   
while True:
    # sensor.messure can only be called ever 3 seconds
    # start at 1 and set to zero in the first loop for our first messurement
    lastMesure += -1
    if lastMesure <= 0:
        try:
            sensor.measure()
            lastMesure = 3
            temp = round((sensor.temperature), 0)
            humid = sensor.humidity
        except:
            print("something went wrong")
    
    
    print("Counter: {:.0f} pumpping:{:0.f}".format(counter, pump.value()))
    print("Temp: {:.0f}℃  HUMIDITY: {:.0F}% ".format(temp, humid))
    
    # if the pump is running
    if pump.value() == 1:
        if counter >= pumpTime: # if it has been the set pump run time
            pump.value(0)      # turn off pump
            counter = 0        # reset counter
        else:
            counter += 1
    else:
        # check current temp
        # if warmer then {lowTemp} check for {hotTime} else check for {normalTime}
        if (temp > lowTemp and counter >= hotTime) or counter >= normalTime:
                pump.value(1)  # turn on pump
                counter = 0    # reset counter
        else:
            counter += 1
    
    # print current data to the screen
    lcd.lcd_clear()
    lcd.lcd_display_string("T: {:.0f}C H:{:.0f}%".format(temp, humid), 1)
    
    if pump.value() == 1:
        status = f'Pumping {pumpTime - counter}s'
        lcd.lcd_display_string(status, 2);
    else:
        lcd.lcd_display_string("Pump off        ", 2)
        
    sleep_ms(1000)
```

here is a picture of my breadboard set up. I have run it both with and without a 1k pull up resistor on the data pin
[image]

Comment: the led is a stand in for the pump while im testing the code

Comment: I seem to remember the DHT22 can only be read every 2 seconds. I would guess the DHT11 is the same. Try lengthening your sleep_ms() time in the while loop.

Comment: Currently I am already delaying the reading to make sure I am only doing it every 3 seconds. The issue is not with getting a reading it is with the reading not always returning the pulse count the library is expecting.